# Bind/Name Server with master domain and multiple subdomains

Tags: email, domain, subdomain, mx-record

I am having a brain fart. I can not figure this out. I am sure someone has asked this before, but just can not seem to find it. (hence the brain fart)

if you look at the following domain names as examples:

```
someserver1.us.example.com 
someserver2.uk.example.com
```

Would be if broke down for explanation purposes as

someserver1 and somserver2 are physical servers. The US and UK would be 2 office far apart
and the example.com would be the master domain.

also for email example:

```
user@example.com
user@someserver1.us.example.com
user@someserver1.uk.example.com
```

What would the bind/named records file look like?

Keep in mind that there is only 1 name server here..

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: Don't know if it's homework or not, but I'm not sure what you're asking -- there's not enough here to deduce what you want to know, so I can't even guess at approximate zone file contents.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
$ORIGIN example.com 
; SOA record, A record for domain, etc.
  MX smtp.example.com

someserver1.uk   10.0.0.1
someserver1.us   10.0.0.2
```

or you can do something like this. ( Of course it would make more sense to seperate the UK and US definitions in different files )

```
$ORIGIN uk.example.com
someserver1   10.0.0.1
$ORIGIN us.example.com
someserver1   10.0.0.2
```

Comment: +1 There's a thousand ways to do what he's asking, and here's two good examples.